# What does 'copy' mean in topology?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I don't know the meaning of 'copy' in the following exercise (Munkres. "*Topology*" 2/e. p. 370. exercise 59.1.):

> Let $X$ be the union of two copies of $S^2$ having a point in common. What is the fundamental group of $X$? Prove that your answer is correct. [Be careful! The union of two simply connected spaces having a point in common is not necessarily simply connected.]

Does it mean a space which is homeomorphic to $S^2$? If I'm right, then how is the topology of $X$(a union two copies) determined?

Comment: Copy usually means disjoint union.  In this case, just fix some some $p_0,q_0\in S^2$ and quotient out by an equivalence relation where $p_0\sim q_0$ and each other point in their respective copy is equivalent to itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, a copy of a topological space $Y$ is a topological space $Y'$ which is homeomorphic to $Y$, but distinct from it in the sense that $Y\neq Y'$.

What the question is describing is basically the space

$$S((-1,0,0), 1)\cup S((1,0,0), 1)$$

where $S(x, r)$ is the sphere, centered around $x$ and with a radius of $r$ (i.e. it's two spheres touching on one point).

Comment: For being a copy you do not need $Y' \ne Y$. But perhaps it is a matter of taste.

Comment: With the standard definition $S^2 = S((0,0,0),1)$ we may take $X = S^2  \cup S((2,0,0),1)$, both $S^2$ and $S((2,0,0),1)$  being copies of $S^2$.

Answer (score 3):

> Let $X$ be the union of two copies of $S^2$ having a point in common.

This is a very non-formal (and not many mathematicians would use that wording) way of simply saying that $X=S^2\vee S^2$ where $\vee$ is [the wedge sum operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedge_sum) a.k.a. glueing at a point. Or in other words these are two spheres touching each other at exactly one point:

[image]

As you can see from the image these are two "copies" of $S^2$.

Comment: What is the purpose of $A$ and $B$? For Seifert - van Kampen?

Comment: @PaulFrost Yeah, that's just a random image I've googled :O

Answer (score 0):

Munkres is a little imprecise when defining $X$ as the union of two copies of $S^2$ having a point in common. In fact, details are left to the reader's imagination.

There is a general construction of the "one-point union" or "wedge" of two spaces $X_i$  endowed with base points $x_i^0$ ($i = 1, 2$). Let us denote the pair $(X_i,x_i^0)$ as a *pointed space*. Then we can construct a pointed space $(W,w^0) = (X_1,x_2^0) \vee (X_2,x_2^0)$ and two continuous base point preserving maps $j_i : (X_i,x_i^0) \to (W,w^0)$ with the following universal property:

For any two continuous base point preserving maps $f_i : (X_i,x_i^0) \to (Z,z^0)$ to any poined space $(Z,z^0)$ there exists a unique continuous base point preserving map $F : (W,w^0) \to (Z,z^0)$ such that $F \circ j_i = f_i$.

If you know some category theory, you will recognize this construct as the *sum* in the category of pointed spaces and continuous base point preserving maps.

There are various explicit constructions. They are all equivalent in the sense that if $(\tilde{W},\tilde{w}^0), \tilde{j}_1, \tilde{j}_2$ form another system with the above universal property, then there exists a unique base point preserving homeomomorphism $h : (W,w^0) \to (\tilde{W},\tilde{w}^0)$ such that $h \circ j_i = \tilde{j}_i$.

Here are three explicit constructions (verification of the universal property omitted):

(1) $W = \{ (x_1,x_2) \in X_1 \times X_2 \mid x_1 = x_1^0 \text{ or } x_2 = x_2^0 \} = X_1 \times \{ x_2^0\} \cup \{ x_1^0\} \times X_2$ with the subspace topology inherited from $X_1 \times X_2$, $w^0 = (x_1^0,x_2^0)$, $j_1(x_1) = (x_1,x_2^0)$, $j_2(x_2) = (x_1^0,x_2)$.

(2) The disjoint union of $X_1, X_2$ may be defined as $X_1 + X_2 = X_1 \times \{ 1 \} \cup X_2 \times \{ 2 \}$ which is topologized by defining $U \subset X_1 + X_2$ to be open if it has the form $U = U_1 \times \{ 1 \} \cup U_2 \times \{ 2 \}$ with open $U_i \subset X_i$. The $X_i \times \{ i \}$ are *copies* of $X_i$ which are made disjoint via the second factor. Note that this also applies for $X_1 = X_2$.

Now define $W$ as the quotient space $(X_1 \times \{ 1 \} \cup X_2 \times \{ 2 \})/\sim$, where $(x_1^0,1) \sim (x_2^0,2)$. Set $w^0 = [x_1^0] = [x_2^0]$, $j_i(x_i) = [(x_i,i)]$.

(3) This variant only works in the following special case: Let $X_i$ be closed subspaces of a space $X$ such that $X_1 \cap X_2$ contains a single point $x^0$. Then we may take $(X_1 \cup X_2,x^0)$ with inclusions $j_i : (X_i,x^0) \hookrightarrow (X_1 \cup X_2,x^0)$ as the a one-point union of $(X_i,x^0)$. This construction is particularly "intuitive" and can be used in Munkres' exercise. See the other answers to your question. Also see exercise 2 on p. 438 of Munkres.

Note that for the approach in (3) it is essential that both $X_i$ are closed in $X$. Consider for example $X = [0,1], X_1 = [0,1), X_2 = \{ 0,1 \}$. Then ordinary union *does not* yield a one-point union.

The universal property has a number of consequences (this could also be seen by using the explicit constructions, but it is nice to work only with the universal property because it indicates *how* to construct the desired system).

(a) Both $j_i$ are embeddings. That is, both $(\tilde{X}_i,\tilde{x}_i^0) \subset (W,w^0)$ are *homeomorphic copies* of $(X_i,x_i^0)$.

In fact, let $c_{21} :  (X_2,x_2^0) \to (X_1,x_1^0)$ denote the map with $c_{21}(X_2) = \{ x_1^0) \}$. Then there exists a unique base point preserving $F: (W,w^0) \to (X_1,x_1^0)$ such that $F \circ j_1 = id : (X_1,x_1^0) \to (X_1,x_1^0)$ and $f \circ j_2 = c_{21}$; similarly for $j_2$. This shows moreover that $j_i$ embeds $(X_i,x_i^0)$ as a pointed retract into $(W,w^0)$.

(b) $\tilde{X}_1 \cup \tilde{X}_2 = W$.

Let $(\tilde{W},\tilde{w}^0) = (\tilde{X}_1 \cup \tilde{X}_2,w^0)$ and let $\tilde{j}_i : (X_i,x_i^0) \to (\tilde{W},\tilde{w}^0)$ be defined by $\tilde{j}_i(x_i) = j_i(x_i)$. It is easy to see that this system has again the universal property, thus the inclusion $(\tilde{W},\tilde{w}^0) \to (W,w^0)$ is a homeomorphism. This implies (b).

(c) $\tilde{X}_1 \cap \tilde{X}_2 = \{ w^0 \}$.

Define $(Z,z^0) = (\{ 0, 1 \}, 0)$ with the trivial topology on $\{ 0, 1 \}$. Let $f_1 : (X_1,x_1^0) \to (Z,z^0), f_1(x_1) = 0$ for all $x_1$ and $f_2 : (X_2,x_2^0) \to (Z,z^0)$, $f_2(x_2^0) = 0$, $f_2(x_2) = 1$ for $x_2 \ne x_2^0$. Both are are continuous maps. There exists a unique map $F : (W,w^0) \to (Z,z^0)$ such that $F \circ j_i = f_i$. For $w \in \tilde{X}_1 \cap \tilde{X}_2$ we can write $w = j_1(x_1) = j(x_2)$ with unique $x_i \in X_i$. Then $0 = f_1(x_1) = F(w) = f_2(x_2)$, hence $x_2 = x_2^0$ and $w = w^0$.